# Setting initial BranchState on AStar traversal using Java embedded API on Neo4j 1.8 and later

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to implement a stateful AStar traversal in Neo4J using the Java embedded API. That is, I'd like to pass an object which holds some contextual information gathered down a branch to use in selecting/pruning onward relationships once I've arrived at a certain node in the graph. The idea being that the `PathExpander.expand()` method would examine the context of the traversal contained in the state object and decide which paths are eligible for expansion, and in which order.  I'm doing this to prevent illegal multi-node subpaths (turn restrictions, actually) from being considered as part of the returned optimal path. This technique works well with the Dijkstra traversal, as the [GraphAlgoFactory](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html) has dijkstra-producing factory methods which support setting an initial state via the [InitialStateFactory](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/InitialStateFactory.html) parameter:

```
dijkstra(PathExpander expander, InitialStateFactory stateFactory, String relationshipPropertyRepresentingCost) 
dijkstra(PathExpander expander, InitialStateFactory stateFactory, CostEvaluator<Double> costEvaluator)
```

Great. However, I cannot find a corresponding factory method to set the initial state in an AStar traversal, the only options being:

```
aStar(PathExpander expander, CostEvaluator<Double> lengthEvaluator, EstimateEvaluator<Double> estimateEvaluator) 
aStar(RelationshipExpander expander, CostEvaluator<Double> lengthEvaluator, EstimateEvaluator<Double> estimateEvaluator)
```

Predictably, my `findSinglePath()` invocation on the [PathFinder](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphalgo/PathFinder.html) instance meets an untimely end with:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Branch state disabled, pass in an initial state to enable it
    at org.neo4j.kernel.Traversal$1.getState(Traversal.java:100)[neo4j-kernel-1.8.jar:1.8]
```

So how does one "pass in an initial state" sans a [InitialStateFactory](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8/org/neo4j/graphdb/traversal/InitialStateFactory.html) parameter on the AStar algorithm factory method? Looking at post 1.8 API docs seems to reveal no (obvious) answer, either.

Alternatively, is there a better way to ensure that a set of "illegal" multinode subpaths never appear in the optimal path returned from `findSinglePath()` invoked on either Dijkstra or AStar PathFinders?

Answer (score 1):

So, the Dijkstra algorithm is implemented in Neo4j using the traversal framework, whereas A* is a custom implementation. There is however a TraversalAStar class which implements A* on top of the traversal framework. That class hasn't got a constructor letting you pass in initial branch state though something that https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/604 addresses.

There has been little focus on comparing and optimize TraversalAStar compared to the one that GraphAlgoFactory provides, but it should provide the functionality you're after... once it gets merged in that is.

Comment: Nice commit. For anyone wondering this is available in 1.9-SNAPSHOT, and seems to be working.